# How to purge "You can’t open the application “q.app” because it may be damaged or incomplete" status?

Tags: macos, bundle, .app

I am trying to create a simple .app bundle. I made a mistake in the Info.plist and the finder shows it with a "barred" sign over the icon, and I get that message when I try to click over it. I fixed the error in the Info.plist, I am sure 100 % the bundle is now ok, but I still get the error message. It seems like Finder detects a broken app and caches it. How do I reset this cache? Even copying the bundle does nothing. I tried tarring and untarring it, and it works, but there must be some magic trick. I thought it was extended attributes, but xattr shows nothing.

Comment: are you able to launch the app now?How are you creating your app?

Comment: Just re install the app and click on replace and not keep both. It should keep you existing preferences and data.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial:
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330759-263.html

My guess is the that the first solution will work: update the prebinding.

Comment: Tutorial appears to be out of date: It's from 2006 (!) and the command line util prescribed in part one doesn't appear to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I had most probably a similar problem. The `Info.plist` file was broken (a wrong `CFBundleExecutable` value), and the Finder was showing the application icon with the barred sign. I edited by hand the `Info.plist` (just `sudo nano Info.plist`), and each time, I tested by right-clicking in Finder and then “show information” (or something like that). When I actually fixed the `Info.plist` file, it was still shown with a bar in the Finder, but was OK in the informations, and it run OK too.

My guess is that your `Info.plist` is still not OK, and I'd suggest editing it by hand (it's just a simple XML file) and deleting the keys one by one until you get no barred sign in the info window.

Answer (score 1):

If you create the app by yourself, check if the entry "CFBundleExecutable" of yourappname.app/Contents/Info.plist coincides with the executable under yourappname.app/Contents/MacOS/ .

For example, if your app has name "Simple", and there is an executable Simple.app/Contents/MacOS/Simple. Then make sure in file Simple.app/Contents/Info.plist, there is an entry :

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>Simple</string>
```